# (Unity) Правильная реализация столкновения NavMeshAgent

Tags: c#, unity3d, navigation

Есть лист NavMeshAgent'ов, которые по клику идут к одной точке. Настройки agent стандартные. Когда вместе пытаются попасть в одно и тоже место, они начинают толкать друг друга, чтобы пробраться в точку. Можно ли как-то избежать столкновений, и сделать так(примерно), чтобы при занятой точке они приближались к ближайшей или останавливались при столкновении? Вот код на движение(самый стандартный):

```
foreach (NavMeshAgent agent in navAgents)
    agent.destination = targetPosition;
```

Вот пример кода из ответа(правильный?)

```
foreach (NavMeshAgent agent in navAgents)
{
    Vector3 MathPosition = new Vector3(targetPosition.x + Random.Range(-2, 2), targetPosition.y + Random.Range(-2, 2), targetPosition.z);
    agent.destination = MathPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для твоего случая, то есть движения группы: 
Тебе нужно взять  targetPosition и рассчитать смещение относительно этой точки для всей группы, То есть каждый NavMeshAgent получит назначение не в targetPosition, а targetPosition.x + x и targetPosition.y+y (смотри картинку).
Этим же способом можно реализовать разные построения (квадрат, круг, шеренга и тд)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update** для комментариев

Random не подходит нужно самостоятельно рассчитать расстояние между юнитами. Нужно учесть **радиус агента** и **желаемое расстояние** между ними, исходя из этого и **количества юнитов** в группе пишешь алгоритм построения (квадрат, круг, шеренга и тд).

PS: Алгоритм не будет простым и придется над ним поработать

Ну и допустим код из комментария кое как подходит(как пример)
Но нужно рассчитать еще и изначальное смещение и шаг:
Например(для квадрата) есть:
AgentCounts = 100;
AgentRadius = 5;
AgentGap = 5;
destenation = Vector3(...);

Тогда:

```
    startX = destenation.x  - (sqrt(AgentCounts)/2)*(AgentRadius + AgentGap);
   startY = destenation.y - (sqrt(AgentCounts)/2)*(AgentRadius + AgentGap);
    for(row = 0; row <  sqrt(AgentCounts); ++row){
      for(col = 0; col <  sqrt(AgentCounts); ++col )
      {
         Vector3 MathPosition = new Vector3(startX , startY , targetPosition.z);
        agent.destination = MathPosition;
        startY += AgentRadius + AgentGap
       }
      startX += AgentRadius + AgentGap
      startY = destenation.y  - (sqrt(AgentCounts)/2)*(AgentRadius + AgentGap);
    }
```

PS2: это псевдокод для демонстрации с чего начать и вряд ли будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я очень глупый. Можете привести пример кода, а я его уже подредактирую? Мне не совсем понятно откуда +x и +y.

Comment: Я в условие добавил пример кода своего, он же так должен выглядеть? Просто они всё равно застревают в друг друге.

Comment: Скорее так: (потому что нужны точные координаты, а не случайные)
`int changeX = -1; //Можно расчитывать на осноыве navAgents.Count, если количевство юнитов всегда разное
int changeY = -1;
bool changeXInThisStep = false;

foreach (NavMeshAgent agent in navAgents)
{
    Vector3 MathPosition = new Vector3(targetPosition.x + changeX, targetPosition.y + changeY, targetPosition.z);
    if (changeXInThisStep) changeX++;
        else changeY++;
    changeXInThisStep = !changeXInThisStep;
    agent.destination = MathPosition;
}`
PS: код не тестировал

Comment: @ssa112112 окей, проверю. Спасибо. Может сегодня Valera Kvip ответит.

Comment: @ValeraKvip как можно из вектора вычесть число, подредактируйте код.(1-ая, 10 стр.)